# Handling requests to and from non-default network interface

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am working on a project that requires me to have multiple network interfaces. I followed the documentation and created three interfaces. I also changed the firewall rules. But even after changing the firewall rules, I am not getting a reply for an ICMP request to the second interface's external IP.
As seen in the screenshot I have allowed all protocols from anywhere to any instance in my network [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbTHV.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the routing table of your VM instance, you'll see that the default route is configured on the primary network interface `eth0`:

```
vm-instance:$ ip route
default via 10.156.0.1 dev eth0
...
```

Whether an Ephemeral or a Static External IP address is configured, this External IP is unknown to the operating system of the VM instance. The External IP address is mapped to the VM's Internal address transparently by VPC. You can verify this with the command

```
vm-instance:$ ip -4 address show
```

You'll see that there are no External IPs bound.
Furthermore, IP packet forwarding is disabled both between the network cards of the VM instance and network interfaces of Google-provided Linux. The commands below can verify that:

```
CloudShell:$ gcloud compute instances describe vm-instance --zone=your-zone | grep canIpForward
vm-instance:$ sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
```

Therefore when a ping packet is received by a secondary interface, it can't reply.

To explore this behavior a bit, you may launch `tcpdump` on the VM instance so that listen on a secondary interface, for example `eth1`:

```
vm-instance:$ sudo apt-get install tcpdump
vm-instance:$ sudo tcpdump -i eth1
```

then find out External IP of your Cloud Shell appliance and ping the secondary External IP of your VM instance from Cloud Shell:

```
CloudShell:$ curl ifconfig.me/ip
CloudShell:$ ping [secondary_ip_of_vm_instance]
```

You'll see in the `tcpdump` output on the console of your VM instance how ICMP packets are arriving to the `eth1` interface from the External IP address of your workstation. But they are not replied.

Google provides explanation of this behavior in the Troubleshooting section of the VPC documentation and suggests possible workarounds:

[Virtual Private Cloud > Doc > Creating instances with multiple network interfaces > Troubleshooting > I am not able to connect to secondary interface using external IP](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces#i_am_not_able_to_connect_to_secondary_interface_using_external_ip):

> The DHCP server programs a default route only on the primary network
> interface of the VM. If you want to connect to the secondary interface
> using an external IP, there are two options. If you only need to
> connect outside the network on the secondary network interface, you
> can set a default route on that network interface. Otherwise, you can
> use [Configuring Policy
> Routing](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces#configuring_policy_routing)
> to configure a separate routing table using source-based policy
> routing in your VM.